# Select second, third, fourth, fifth, largest number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, max

I have a question about how to select the second, third, fourth, and fifth largest number in a table. To select the biggest row I use:

```
$max = SELECT max(money) FROM table
```

Right now I want to specify `$second_max`, `$third_max`, `$fourth_max` and `$fifth_max`.

Does someone know how to change my previous SQL `select max()` easy to specify second max, third max etc...?

I do not want to use:

```
select money from table order by money desc limit 5;
```

Because I want them all in different variables.

Comment: which dbms, oracle or mss sql or mysql

Comment: `SELECT money FROM table ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 0,1` for the first; `SELECT money FROM table ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 1,1` for the second; `SELECT money FROM table ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 2,1` for the third; etc... or `SELECT money FROM table ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 0,5` to get the top 5 in descending order

Comment: ```SELECT `money` FROM `table` ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 1, 4``` will return rows 2, 3, 4 and 5. Obviously, if you want to get all 5 rows, you will need to do what everyone else has suggested and use `limit 5`.

Answer (score 0):

`select money from table order by money desc LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to get them on separate rows:

```
select t.money
from table t
group by t.money
order by money desc
limit 5;

The next easiest thing is to put them in a comma-separated list:

select group_concat(money order by money desc) as monies
from (select t.money
      from table t
      group by t.money
      order by money desc
      limit 5
     ) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

```
SELECT money
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY money DESC
LIMIT 5
```

You'll get a 5-record result set, ordered by the top money values - assuming you actually have 5+ records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

USE SQL

```
select money from table order by money desc limit 5;
```

The five rows are there as max, secondary,... value of money.

Answer (score 0):

In ORACLE you could do the following :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT ADRESSID, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ADRESSID DESC) AS ROW_NUM
  FROM ADRESSTABLE       
) t
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
OR ROW_NUM = 3
OR ROW_NUM = 5;
```